# "Object with this Object already exists" error using ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a website with a collection of menus from restaurants in my town. As you know every restaurant has a menu comprised of sections(Appetizers, Entrees, etc) with different items under each section(I.e under Appetizers: Mozzarella Sticks, Nachos, etc.) I have the following models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name

class MenuSection(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(
        Restaurant,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    food_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.food_type


class MenuItem(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(
        Restaurant,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    MenuSection = models.ForeignKey(
        MenuSection,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    food_item = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.food_item
```

Obviously, food sections and food items are going overlap between restaurants. I thought this would not be an issue but in my db I have two `Restaurant` objects, one already has a `MenuSection` named "Appetizers", I tried to give the second `Restaurant` a `MenuSection` named "Appetizers" and it will not let me do so, saying: "Menu item with this MenuSection already exists." How can I fix this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Well, first of all your `MenuSection` model is wrongly defined because you set the restaurant as the primary key of the `MenuSection`. This will give you AT MOST one `MenuSection` per restaurant. Not what you want I presume.

Comment: On the other hand I don know whether Django allows you to set more than one field as the `primary_key` of the model. In Django this is usually done letting it add the default autofield ID as primary key and use the `Meta` attribute `unique_together`

Comment: At last, are you sure you are using a *different* `MenuSection` that happens to have the same `food_type` value? (`'Appetizers'`) Because if you are using the same object the error would totally make sense.

Comment: I thought a `ForeignKey` was a many-to-one field? I thought that would mean I could associate many `MenuSection`'s with one `Restaurant`? @ivissani

Comment: It is, but setting a FK also as the primary key 'transforms' it in a One-to-One relation. Think of it a little bit. A FK from A to B is stored in A just as the pk value of the related row in B. If this column is also set as PK (implying uniqueness) lets you with at most one row in A per each row in B. In order to be a Many-to-one relation you have to remove the `primary_key` attribute from your FK an define another primary key for that model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make it the primary key, just take that bit out and let Django generate the primary key automatically. Since it is one to many you will get a table with one entry "Appetizer" for every restaurant you add it to. Alternatively you could make it a many to many, and all restaurants with an appetizer section will point to the same menus section item in the table